# Generating SAML request and Extracting SAML token from response in web browser

Tags: angular, saml-2.0

I have very limited knowledge of SAML. I am working on a browser app which get the data through REST APIs. The API request at the provider can be validated by either by providing the user credentials or through SAML SSO.
 Documentation of API provider says that 
`If you acquired the token from an SSO source, the Authorization header is of the format:
Authorization: SSO2Token <SSO_SAML_TOKEN>`. Now since I don't have any backend service running, how can I generated SAML request in Angular 2 app for SAML host and then extract the SAML token from SAML response and use it in subsequent API call header.

Answer (score 1):

The SAML SSO flows were designed with a browser in mind sending SAML messages to a web application either as HTTP redirects or HTTP Posts. I would recommend you to understand how SAML works (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) and the approach mentioned here might work for you: [Angularjs and SAML, the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164639/angularjs-and-saml-the-beginning)